# Access violation, when using shared_ptr on legacy code

Tags: visual-c++, shared-ptr, access-violation

I implement a new module using shared_ptr etc. in our legacy app, however I get a access violation, when shared_ptr is calling the destructor.

app:

```
case ENUM_DATA:
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CDataMsg> msg(new CDataMsg(_stringmsg)); // _stringmsg is initialized before
    Process(msg);
    break;
}
```

Process():

```
bool Process(std::tr1::shared_ptr<CDataMsg> msg)
{
    try
    {
        switch (msg->getDataType())
        {
            case ENUM_MYDATATYPE:
            {
                std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyData> base(msg->getData());
                std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyDataChild> data(std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<CMyDataChild>(base));

                // do some stuff with data
                std::tr1::shared_ptr<CRequest> request(new CRequest(data->getParam1(), data->getParam2()));
                handler->AddRequest(request->getBin());
                break;
            }
            default:;
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // exception handling
    }
    return false;
}
```

Destructor:

```
CDataMsg::~CDataMsg()
{
    if (m_data)
        delete m_data;
    m_data = NULL;
}
```

m_data is a CMyData* (cannot be changed at this point).

CDataMsg is a container, which holds data of type CMyData. CmyDataChild is a subclass of CMyData, which is used here.

I have breakpoint in the destructor, but the debugger stops only, when shared_ptr is calling it and then I get the access violation already.

Comment: Does `msg->getData()` allocate and return a new `CMyData` object or does it return a pointer to a `CMyData` that is a member of `msg`?

Comment: returns a pointer to a CMyData member of msg

Comment: Whenever you're dealing with heap corruption, a standard C++ class is the last place to look for the cause.  Use the debug allocator from `<crtdbg.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have confirmed in your comment `msg->getData()` returns a pointer to a member variable of `msg` (presumably `m_data`) and it will be deleted when this `switch` block scope exits:

```
case ENUM_MYDATATYPE:
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyData> base(msg->getData());
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyDataChild>
        data(std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<CMyDataChild>(base));

    // do some stuff with data
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CRequest>
        request(new CRequest(data->getParam1(), data->getParam2()));
    handler->AddRequest(request->getBin());
    break;
}
```

The destructor of `msg` will be invoked later when this `switch` block scope exits:

```
case ENUM_DATA:
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CDataMsg> msg(new CDataMsg(_stringmsg));
    Process(msg);
    break;
}
```

and attempt to re`delete` the member variable `m_data`.

Also:

```
case ENUM_MYDATATYPE:
{
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyData> base(msg->getData());
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyDataChild>
        data(std::tr1::static_pointer_cast<CMyDataChild>(base));
    ...
}
```

`data` is pointing to the same object as `base`. When this scope exits `base` will be `deleted`ed twice.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Following your above comment, I checked on the   `CMyData*` returned by `getData()`. However, I could fix it by using `shared_ptr` as return type. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I see bugs like this, I immediately think double delete.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<CMyData> base(msg->getData());
if (m_data) delete m_data;  //- in CDataMsg destructor
```

Is it possible that 'm_data' is being deleted twice?  Once in the shared_ptr and once in the CDataMsg destructor.